# Testing a Flask application with requests

Tags: python, flask, python-requests

Ever since I read

> A untested application is broken

in the flask documentation about testing [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/testing/)

I have been working down my list of things to make for some of my applications.

I currently have a flask web app when I write a new route I just write a `requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', auth=('user', 'pass'))`, post, put, etc to test the route.

Is this a decent alternative? Or should I try and do tests via what [flask's documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/testing/) says, and if so why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fundamentally it's the same concept, you are running functionality tests as they do. However, you have a prerequisite, a live application running somewhere (if I got it right). They create a fake application (aka mock) so you can test it without being live, e.g. you want to run tests in a CI environment.

In my opinion it's a better alternative than a live system. Your current approach consumes more resources on your local machine, since you are required to run the whole system to test something (i.e. at least a DB and the application itself). In their approach they don't, the fake instance does not need to have real data, thus no connection to a DB or any other external dependency.

I suggest you to switch to their testing, in the end you will like it.